# Searching by Name Using Geocomplete Jquery Library

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-places-api, geocomplete

Using the Geocomplete Jquery Plugin for Google Maps (http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) I can successfully search for addresses in the Google Places API.  However, does anyone know if it is possible to search for a named placed such as “Madison Square Garden” or “Wells Fargo Center”?

Comment: Those are "places", not addresses (the Geocoder resolves addresses).  You would find them with the [Google Maps Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/)

Answer (score 2):

Set the types: to ['geocode','establishment'] in defaults of jquery.geocomplete.js

Comment: also remember to change 'type' to 'types' . This had me stuck for awhile. =/

Answer (score 1):

For rails geocode, the code would be this:

```
<script>
  $(".geocomplete").geocomplete({
    types: ['geocode','establishment']
  });
</script>
```